# Session not passing to ajax (HttpOnly:Secure)

Tags: php, ajax, apache, session

My main file is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION["foo"]="foo"; 
?>
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "hoho2.php",
        });
```

And my hoho2.php is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Now, In my main file, where I am doing the `print_r`, I get the correct session data - `foo -> foo`. But in my hoho2.php file, I get the empty array. 
Why is session not passing through ajax call? 
Is it possible because I have Set-Cookie: HttpOnly:Secure ?

**Update:**
I have figured out that It indeed it because of HttpOnly:Secure that my session is not persisted. What can I do ?

Comment: the same code works in my case

Comment: What is `Set-Cookie: HttpOnly:Secure`? It's not referenced in your code anywhere.

Comment: @miken32 This is apache setting.